# $f_n(x)=n\sin^{2n+1}x\cos x$. Find $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)$

Tags: calculus, limits, definite-integrals, uniform-convergence

Let $f_n(x)=n\sin^{2n+1}x\cos x$. Then find the value of

$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\displaystyle\int_0^{\pi/2}f_n(x)\;dx-\displaystyle\int_0^{\pi/2}(\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}f_n(x))\;dx$

My Thoughts: If the function is uniformly convergent, the answer should be zero.

To check for uniform convergence, I need to do Weierstrass's M-Test.

A ratio test says $f_n(x)$ is convergent provided $x<\pi/2$. How do I properly solve this problem ? Please help.

Comment: The answer for the second part would be zero :$0<nsin^{2n+1}x<nx^{2n+1}<nx^n$ and $lim_{n\to \infty}nx^n=0$

Comment: but we don't know if |x|<1 !

Comment: Could we use $sin^n(x)<sin^{n-1}x$ to say that $0<nsin^{2n+1}x<nsin^nx$. Now, let $y=sin x$, we have $|y|<1$and so, $ny^n \to 0$ ?

Comment: wow .. thanks for all the help .. :)

Comment: is this function not uniformly convergent ?

Comment: Can I ask you : where did you find this question ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21399/discussion-between-square-one-and-srinivas-k).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an approach.
$$ \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\displaystyle\int_0^{\pi/2}f_n(x)\;dx = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}n\displaystyle\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^{2n+1}( x )\cos(x)\;dx$$

$$ =\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{n}{2n+2} \sin^{2n+2}( x )\bigg|_{x=0}^{\pi/2}=\dots\,.  $$

Comment: this would be 1/2 and the second part would be $\infty$. so the answer would be $-\infty$ ?

Comment: @square_one: Just take your time to finish the problem. What's the second part?

Comment: $-\displaystyle\int_0^{\pi/2}(\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}f_n(x))\;dx$